# How can I apply a median filter to an signal (array) on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, median

I have a signal which is an array (length m) and I have a noise of type salt and papper. I already applied a low pass filter (LPF) to it and got really good result. However I want to apply a median filter to the signal and compare with the results apllying the LPF).

I know the function is the `medfilt1(X,N)`, but don't know what the N stands for.

The function is: `y = medfilt1(X,X,BLKSZ,DIM)` and I want to a apply it to an array `raw_Signal <5000x1double>`.

For the singal X `raw_Signal` I used the

```
N=3 %the default number
BLKSZ= 5 
DIM = 1 %apply the filter to the rows
```

The output of the function is a filtered signal, but I don't understand the input N very well. Can anyone explain it to me with an example.

Answer (score 1):

N is how many samples are used to compute each median.  So if your signal is [a b c d e f g], and N is 3, then the second output is the median([a b c]).  The third is median([b c d]), etc.  The first output is a little problematic because you'd try to use a non-existent sample, so it's just median([0 a b]);

Hand-wavy intuition advice follows (don't take this as an exact description): In general, the larger the N, the more filtering will take place.  Consider this:  if you only ever have one noise point (outlier) in any 3 samples, then the median of the other 2 will be a very good estimate, and all the noise is filtered.  If you have 2 noise points in a particular group of 3 samples, then the median will end up choosing 1 of the 2 noise points.  N=5 would catch it, but will perturb your non-noisy points more.

Don't mess with BLKSZ.  As the help text says, use it only if you're low on memory, and if you are, pick BLKSZ so that BLKSZ x N x 8 (size of the working matrix in bytes) is somewhere between 1MB and 100MB.  Otherwise, leave it out.  And since you have a vector, DIM=1 is assumed, so Y = medfilt1(X,N) is all you need.

Comment: Ok, actually I was misunderstanding the N with the BLKSZ. Actually I don't know what it is the BLKSZ but I know what's N.

Can you explain what is the BLKSZ it? How is it related with the memory of the CPU?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  **y = medfilt1(x,n,blksz) uses a for-loop to compute blksz (block size) output samples at a time.** It further describes that computing blksz output samples will require a working matrix of N x blksize.  blksize is by default length(x) (in other words, compute all output samples in one pass).  If that hangs up your machine, or fails to complete, pick blksize as I describe above.

Answer (score 1):

A 1D median filter on a point X works by taking `N/2-1` of the adjacent values, sorting them, and returning the median value. A practical example:

```
x=[1,1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1]

x(4), N=3 => [1,(2),3] => median(x(4)) = 2

x(4), N=5 => [1,1,(2),3,4] => median(x(4)) = 2
```

but

```
x(6), N=3 => [3,4,1] => [1,(3),4] median(x(6)) = 3

x(6), N=5 => [2,3,4,1,1] => [1,1,(2),3,4] => median(x(6)) = 2
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is the length of the filter. Generally speaking, the k-th value is the median of the N/2 previous values and the N/2 following values.

Namely,

> For n odd, y(k) is the median of x(k-(n-1)/2:k+(n-1)/2).
>
> For n even, y(k) is the median of x(k-n/2), x(k-(n/2)+1), ...,
>   x(k+(n/2)-1). In this case, medfilt1 sorts the numbers, then takes the
>   average of the n/2 and (n/2)+1 elements